# Few configurations are not able to edit. - Magento Enterprise Edition 2.4.X

Tags: magento2, admin, magento-enterprise, configuration, backend

[image]

Red mark configurations are disable, not able to edit.

What should i check?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: please try this command  and set your value as per requirement.
php bin/magento app:config:dump

Comment: Also, refer this URL - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-config-mgmt-set.html

Answer (score 1):

Check the following article from Mark Shust regarding config settings priority: https://m.academy/blog/magento-2-configuration-settings-fallback-process/

Basically, if it is disabled in the admin panel, it is set in one of these places:

1. app/etc/config.php
2. app/etc/env.php
3. Environment variable
   Where #3 has the highest precedence

Answer (score 0):

If you can set configuration in admin so quick solution as per below but why it's not changing from admin. I will find the root cause for that and update you.

Use Below Command for - Disable(0) / Enable(1) from SSH/Putty/CMD.

Merge Minify JS

```
php bin/magento config:set dev/js/merge_files 0

php bin/magento config:set dev/js/minify_files 0
```

JS Bundling

```
php bin/magento config:set dev/js/enable_js_bundling 0
```

Merge Minify CSS

```
php bin/magento config:set dev/css/merge_css_files 0

php bin/magento config:set dev/css/minify_files 0
```

CSS Critical Path

```
php bin/magento config:set dev/css/use_css_critical_path 0
```

Minify HTML

```
php bin/magento config:set dev/template/minify_html 0
```

After all configuration set using above command then must run below command.

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the configurations are set in app/etc/config.php.
If any configuration is set via app/etc/config.php then that particular field is disable in the admin.